# How To save images to iphone simulator 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I am trying to add images in iphone simulator 4.2. I did this with older versions like
drag images in simulator ,then click image to save. It works fines but this same approach is note working for 4.2 simulator. I also manually copied images to Library/Applicationsuuport/iphone simulator/4.2/Media/DCIM/100Apple.. Please help about this

Comment: I have tested in 4.3 and its work properly.

Comment: [This](http://www.ke-cai.net/2010/11/add-images-to-iphone-simulator-41.html) post might helpful to you

Comment: you can then try by making a sample project and write a code for adding image in it.By doing this your image will be saved in your iPhone simulator

Comment: Check this http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Mobile-Applications/17501-Adding-photo-to-iPhone-simulator.html

Answer (score 9):

Adding Photo to iPhone simulator photo library

1) Open and save image on your Desktop

2) Drag it to simulator, then Safari opens (or browse to the Image in the internet using Safari)

3) Hold your click on the image

4)When the pop-up appears, choose Save Image

5) for iOS Simulator 4.2, do these steps twice to get it work.